# unattended custom installation

Tags: raspbian, boot, software-installation

Thanks to "raspbian-ua-netinst" I am able to setup my Pi unattended.
I would like ot run a couple of shell scripts after the first boot.

They actually do nothing more than change the file "/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf in order to modeprobe a couple of kernel modules:

- modprobe i2c_bcm2708
- modprobe i2c-dev

Is there anyway to automate this actions after the first boot?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about what you're specifically trying to do, but you can get raspbian-ua-netinst to do additional things after install by adding a post-install.txt file in the same location as installer-config.txt (should be in the FAT/boot partition).

post-install.txt basically runs as a script

Have a look at [rcS](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/master/scripts/etc/init.d/rcS) to get a feel for when it runs and what you can do with it (although it may have changed since the version you are working with, if so best to check the rcS relevant to the version you are using e.g. [rcS from v1.1.x](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/v1.1.x/scripts/etc/init.d/rcS)).

Source and further info: https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/issues/155